# while storing value from datatable to variable it either says server side not defined or the variable goes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Hi I am trying to do text based individual column search in datable but when I am storing the data from the datatable function in a variable it goes undefined please help.

I want to search while using scroll as the data that I will be handling is to large

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2ygD.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //// DataTable
    //var table = $('#tblCity').DataTable();

    //// Apply the search
    //table.columns().every(function () {
    //    var that = this;

    //    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
    //        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
    //            that
    //                .search(this.value)
    //                .draw();
    //        }
    //    });
    //});

    $('#tblCity tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });


    var table = $('#tblCity').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        serverSide: true,
        ordering: true,
        searching: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/City/GetCity",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "JSON",
            "error": function (jqXHR, exception) {
                if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
                    window.location.href = '/City/List';
                }
            }
        },
        "columns": [{
            "data": "CountryName"
        }, {
            "data": "StateName"
        }, {
            "data": "CityName"
        }, {
            "data": "ActiveText"
        }],

        scrollY: 200,
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator: true
        },
        //initComplete: function () {
        //    this.api().columns().every(function () {
        //        var that = this;
        //        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
        //            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
        //                that
        //                    .search(this.value)
        //                    .draw();
        //            }
        //        })
        //    })
        //},
        stateSave: true
    });


    // Apply the search
    table.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                that
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```html
@model IList<DataTableExample.EDMX.usp_GetCityList_Result>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>



    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tblCity">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Country </th>
                <th> State </th>
                <th> City </th>
                <th> Active </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @*<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.CountryName</td>
                    <td>@item.StateName</td>
                    <td>@item.CityName</td>
                    <td>@item.ActiveText</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>*@
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th> Country </th>
                <th> State </th>
                <th> City </th>
                <th> Active </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.5.1/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTableScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I initially wanted to do pagination but turns out this datatables are better option can some one please help.
Thanks..
please help

Comment: Why don't you also include your HTML as code here? [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: added the html @Luca